# What does the '..' in 'SELECT * FROM database..table' mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I understand than in a SQL statement, that the `xxx` portion of, say, `xxx.TableName` references the schema of the data table.  Typically, most tables are created as `dbo.TableName`.  When referencing a table in SQL code, the default schema can be left out and you can just reference the table by the table name.  Likewise, if you need to reference a table within another database, you can reference it by the following syntax `Database.dbo.TableName`.

However, I just ran into another users code which has `Database..TableName`.  What does the `..` represent?  I can assume a reasonable answer but I can't find any concrete documentation.  (Google doesn't seem to work well with the double-dot text.)

Comment: Apologies if this is a duplicate.  Please provide a link and I'll delete this question immediately.  Again, I tried to search for it but the double-dot text isn't very searchable.

Comment: Here is an [article](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) about why you shouldn't leave that out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is short hand to use the default schema.

`select x from steve..mark` is logical equivlant as `select x from steve.dbo.mark` as long as dbo is the default schema

[three part naming convention for sql server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx)

[msdn FROM CLAUSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx)

Comment: That's what I'd assumed.  You have a reference for that?

Comment: Also, is this new to a specific version of SQL Server, or has this been around for a long time, just not typically used by most SQL devs?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen it used all the way back to 2005 or 2008. Aside from forum posts, though, I've never seen any real documentation for it

Comment: I have seen it as far back as 2005

Comment: Interesting, I've searched through all of the documentation you've provided.  I could just be missing it, but I don't see any reference claiming that the schema is optional.  Obviously, it is, but I would like to read a little more on the subject.  Maybe there are a few other shorthand options that I'm just unaware of.